# Tagging Item Versions

Tags: versions

Is it possible to tag the versions of the items.

Example :

Version 1,2,3 will be tagged to Phase 1

Version 4,5,6 will be tagged to Phase 2

Comment: Can you add more information about what you're trying to achieve? Will the tagging be used to hold to publishing for example?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes you can

Tagging is a field that is stored as `__Semantics` and it is not shared between item versions. I ran a quick test.

#### Version 2, untagged.

[image]

#### Version 1, tagged

[image]

#### And searching for this tag

[image]

Returns only Version 1, as expected.

#### And final proof

I tagged both versions.

[image]

Further reading: [Content Tagging with Sitecore 7](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_7_development_team/posts/content-tagging-with-sitecore-7)

Comment: Thanks Mark. For some reason the search of the tag is showing only one version in the result set though i had tagged three versions.

Comment: Make sure your indexes are configured correctly, then rebuild the indexes.

Comment: Hello Mark,Rebuilt the index. Only the latest Version is fetched in the search result. Example: i had applied the test tag to version 3 and 4. The search result is populates only version 4

Comment: hello Mark, still i'm facing the issue. only the latest tagged version is displaying